# Local MongoDB drops database without any cause

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, drop

I have a DB on my ssh server (ubuntu), also i have backups of this DB. Suddenly today the DB has been dropped fully. I thought that it is my fault, although everything was working over a week and nothing was wrong, I used backup and fixed it, but now it happens twice. Can it be an evidence of any code errors / db setting errors (i have no EVEN mentions in my code about dropping collection). Or the one cause is that smb connects to my db and drops it? (I have no password to connect)

Comment: look at server logs to understand what happens

Comment: @dododo but nothing is in the logs

Comment: something should be :) On a client side you also can configure change stream events like Drop: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/#drop-event (for dropping collection), Rename or DropDatabase that at least should trigger an event when this issue appear which will show at least timing when this happens

Comment: btw is only one db removed? What happens with other? If you have only single one, try creating a test one and see what will happen with it